# String to Date in a PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to use setDate() in a PreparedStatement, however the date that I have is in the format of 2008-07-31. The code is:

```
 pstmt.setDate(f++, (Date) DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT).parse(value.substring(0, 10)));
```

However, it gives me the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2008-07-31"
```

Why is this?

Comment: What is the default date format you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need make sure the default DateFormat is in `yyyy-MM-dd` format (usually it's a config in OS), or you can use `SimpleDateFormat` or `java.sql.Date` to parse date string.

```
java.util.Date d;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");
d = sdf.parse ("2008-07-31");

// or
d = java.sql.Date.valueOf ("2008-07-31");
```

or, you could just set parameter as String, if the underlying database driver support the `VARCHAR`/`CHAR` to `DATE` conversion.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a very specific date, don't ask Java to use a *default* date format - set it yourself.

For example:

```
DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = parser.parse(value.substring(0, 10));
```

You should also potentially set the time zone of the parser... my guess is that UTC is the most appropriate time zone here.

Note that this has nothing to do with prepared statements as such - it's *just* date parsing.

(As an alternative to using `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat`, you could use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) which has a nicer API and thread-safe formatters/parsers. You can ask Joda Time to convert from its own types to `Date` values. Possibly overkill if you *only* need it for parsing here, but if you're doing anything else with dates, it's well worth looking into.)

Answer (score 1):

DateFormat.DEFAULT points to MEDIUM format and MEDIUM format looks like Jan 12, 1952. So, you may have create a SimpleDateFormat object with the format you are using.

Answer (score 0):

First convert `String` to `Date` and then set that to `PreparedStatement`. Check with below code.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd"); 
Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is mismatch in the format of the date that you are providing as input and the format in which you have specified while formatting which is default in your case.

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormay("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Try using the same format for both the dates.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use

```
pstmt.setDate(f++, 
              new java.sql.Date(
                  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                      .parse(value.substring(0, 10))
                      .getTime()
                  )
             );
```